# Firefox plugin or addon to show authentication negotiation details

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, authentication

I would like to see all the authentication communication between Firefox and a web site, similar to what `curl -v` shows. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

One of these must do the job for you:

- [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)
- [Header Spy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/header-spy/)
- [HTTPS Finder](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/https-finder/)

> HTTPS Finder sends a quick (and small) request to each website you
>   visit, determining if the site supports the HTTPS protocol.

You may also want to take a look at [Certificate Patrol](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/), [HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) and other extensions on [this list](http://cryptogasm.com/2011/05/best-security-privacy-add-ons-for-firefox/).